# How to use getTarget in javafx?

Tags: javafx

the problem is that the IntelliJ idea does not allow me to use the `getTarget()` method. The basic idea is to show `AnchorPane` when you click on `jfxbutton`. How to do it? I have a feeling that I need to connect a library but which one.

**Controller**

```
package sample;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javafx.event.EventTarget;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.animation.*;

public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane area;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane per;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton btn_per;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton btn_area;
    int i = 1;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction (MouseEvent event) {
        if (event.getTarget() == btn_per) { //This
            per.setVisible(true);
        }
    }


    public void initialize() {
        btn_per.setOnAction(event -> {
            per.setVisible(true);
            area.setVisible(false);
        });

        btn_area.setOnAction(event -> {
            per.setVisible(false);
            area.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Import `javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent` instead of `java.awt.event.MouseEvent`. Furthermore if you use the `onAction` event the correct parameter type is `ActionEvent` instead of `MouseEvent`. Also use `getSource` instead of `getTarget`. Using multiple handlers for different nodes instead of checking the source should be prefered though.

Comment: Additionally, it's generally recommended that you define a separate method for each specific action, and only register that handler method with specific controls that should invoke that action. That way, there is no need to test the target (or source, which is probably what you really want) of the event.

Comment: Also either register the handlers from fxml or use the `initialize` method for this purpose, but not both. Using `setOnAction` replaces the handler. If you need to add multiple handlers, you should use `addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, eventHandler);`